# Implementing expand and collapse in Rails views

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I wanted to implement expand and collapse in my application. I tried to follow this link for the implementation 
http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html 
hanks 
I have no knowledge of JQuery so not getting what to modify in the .html file in the above link provided to use it as .rhtml file
I have copied the images to public/images directory
and javascript to public/javascript directory and tried to use the html code provided in the above directory to use as view. I modified the .rhtml to include the link to image and javascript. But it is not working.

But I have no knowledge of JQuery, can any one guide how can i make use of this .html file as view in my Rails application.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery UI [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget might be what you need. It has little to do with Rails though. Just create the HTML in your template and configure the widget in Coffeescript (or JavaScript if you prefer).

Comment: Thanks the link provided was indeed use full, but lacks ExpandAll and CollapseAll links.